# Cognito post verification lambda call causes failure

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a lambda function that is invoked when a cognito user submits their verification code.

```
PostConfirmation failed with error RequestId: 3241xxxx-3cxx-11xx-aexx-8b39059xxxxx Process exited before completing request.
    at constructor.e (<anonymous>:21:4685)
    at constructor.callListeners (<anonymous>:21:24558)
    at constructor.emit (<anonymous>:21:24267)
    at constructor.emitEvent (<anonymous>:21:18671)
    at constructor.a (<anonymous>:21:14521)
    at d.runTo (<anonymous>:22:12444)
    at <anonymous>:22:12651
    at constructor.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:21:14731)
    at constructor.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:21:18726)
    at constructor.callListeners (<anonymous>:21:24664)
```

And my lambda function's job is to receive that submission and publish a message to SQS, and then continue.

```
module.exports.trigger_userVerified = (event, context, callback) => {
  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

  var nickname = event.request.userAttributes.nickname;

  var params = {
    MessageBody: 'A user has registered an account and has supplied a website address.',
    QueueUrl: ' https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxx/my_sqs_queue',
    DelaySeconds: 0,
    MessageAttributes: {
      'nickname': {
        DataType: 'String',
        StringValue: nickname
      }
    }
  };
  sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    context.done(null, event);
  });

};
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm handling this lambda function that causes this error? how do I investigate further?

Comment: Do you discover the problem? I have the same!

Answer (score 0):

The  error "Process exited before completing request" means that the lambda Javascript function exited before calling context.done (or context.succeed, etc.). Most of the times this means that there is an error in the function.

I'm not a Javascript expert (at all) so there may be more elegant ways to find the error but my approach has been to put a bunch of console.log messages in my code, run it, and then look at the logs. I can usually zero in on the offending line and, if I look at it long enough, I can usually figure out my mistake.

Since it's lambda:
Please check your cloudwatch logs and see if you can find more. In your place I would add some console.log statements as well.